# Give an example of a sequence of zero-mean, finite variance random variables, with divergent sum of variance, and converging to $1$.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I am working on an exercise stated as follows:

> Assuming $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_{k}=\infty$, give an example of independent random variables $(X_{k})$ such that $Var(X_{k})\leq p_{k}<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{k}=0$ such that $\limsup_{n}X_{n}=1$ almost surely and $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}kX_{k}=\infty$.

The first example coming to my mind is just to take $X_{k}=1$ for all $k$, so we have the desired divergent sum and $\limsup X_{n}=1$, and $Var(X_{k})=0$, but firstly $\mathbb{E}X_{k}=1$, not $0$ and I don't know if they are independent or not....

I have no other idea for now... I can take something like $$\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=-1)=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=1)=1/2,$$ but then it is really hard to compute the infinite sum and $\limsup$...

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: For the very last part, you also want the limsup?

Comment: @PhoemueX oh I think $\lim$ is okay enough.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to give an example for a given choice of $(p_n)$. That is the way the question sounds so the condition $var(X_k) \leq p_k$ may not be satisfied in your example.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Yes you are right.. That is also part of my confusion.. Thanks for pointing it out!